# Sparkline with custom array

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, angularjs, sparklines

I have this code for my sparkline chart:

```
       <div sparkline="" values="4,4,7,5,9,6,4" data-type="line" data-height="80" data-width="100%" data-line-width="2" data-line-color="#dddddd" data-spot-color="#bbbbbb" data-fill-color="" data-highlight-line-color="#fff" data-spot-radius="3"
           data-resize="true"></div>
           <!-- Bar chart-->
           <div class="text-center">
           <div sparkline="" data-bar-color="#fff" data-height="50" data-bar-width="6" data-bar-spacing="6" values="1,3,4,7,5,9,4,4,7,5,9,6,4"></div>
        </div>
```

I just want to change the **values** attr for my array of data, like this:

```
<div sparkline="" values="{{myArray}}"...
```

I am using AngularJs, and I tryed to create an array like :

```
vm.charData = [1,3,4,7,5,9,4,4,7,5,9,6,4];
```

But it dont get it as possible. What can I do? I tryed to use jQuery as well but it shows me this error

**$element.sparkline is not a function**

If anyone know how can I put my custom array that would be awesome, ty :D

Comment: where do you want to put an array `[1,3,4,7,5,9,4,4,7,5,9,6,4]` ? in `div`? if yes - you have 3 `div`s... Make your question clearer

Comment: in the attr of values, right now my table show that values --> 4,4,7,5,9,6,4 I just want to put an array, see the question now

Answer (score 3, accepted):

in HTML add `class` to your `<div>`

```
<div class='yourClass' sparkline="" values="4,4,7,5,9,6,4" data-type="line" data-height="80" data-width="100%" data-line-width="2" data-line-color="#dddddd" data-spot-color="#bbbbbb" data-fill-color="" data-highlight-line-color="#fff" data-spot-radius="3"
           data-resize="true"></div>
```

in js:

```
vm.charData = [1,3,4,7,5,9,4,4,7,5,9,6,4];

document.querySelector('.yourClass').setAttribute('values', vm.charData);
```

if you are using jQuery:

```
$('.yourClass').attr('values', vm.charData);
```